# Functional inequality proof?

Tags: inequality

Let $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$, $g(x, y) = x+y$ with $x>0, y>0$. Assume $f(x_2, y_2) > f(x_1, y_1)$. What can you say about the value of $\frac{g(x_2, y_2)}{g(x_1, y_1)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $(x_2,y_2)$ is such that $f(x_2,y_2)=R^2$ and choose $r^2$ such that $r^2<R^2$ and the line through $(0,R)$ and $(R,0)$[image] has two points, say $P$ and $Q$, in commons with the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (you can always do this provided $r^2$ is not to small compared with $R^2$. Let be $F=(0,r)$,  $G=(r,0)$. Now, if $(x_2,y_2)=(0,R)$ and
$(x_1,y_1)=(0,r)$ you have, of course that $f(x_2,y_2)>f(x_1,y_1)$ as well as $g(x_2,y_2)>g(x_1,y_1)$. The same hold if you choose   $(x_2,y_2)=(0,R)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ on the arc FP. But if you choose $(x_2,y_2)=(0,R)$ and  $(x_1,y_1)=(x_P,y_P)$ then you have
$f(x_2,y_2)>f(x_1,y_1)$ and $g(x_2,y_2)=g(x_1,y_1)$. Finally, if you choose  $(x_1,y_1)$ within the arc $PQ$ you still have $f(x_2,y_2)>f(x_1,y_1)$ but $g(x_2,y_2)<g(x_1,y_1)$. If you know that $r^2\leq\frac{R^2}{2}$ then $f(x_2,y_2)>f(x_1,y_1)$ implies  $g(x_2,y_2)\geq g(x_1,y_1)$, while with
$r^2<\frac{R^2}{2}$ you have that $f(x_2,y_2)>f(x_1,y_1)$ implies  $g(x_2,y_2)> g(x_1,y_1)$.

Comment: Please do not answer questions without context. See [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: I still don't understand, why  point $(x1,y1)$ on arc $FP$ that can $g(x2, y2)$ > $g(x1, y1)$, and I also want to know what software you use draw the picture,I am a math beginner.

Comment: Since the function $g(x,y)=x+y$ is constant on the line $x+y=k$ you have that $g(x_2,y_2)=R^2>r^2=g(x_1,y_1)$. The software is Geogebra and you can find it at https://www.geogebra.org. It is free.

Comment: this I know, but I don't know point relation on $g(x,y)= x+y$ , when the point on the different circle.

Comment: why $x^2+y^2=r^2$ can get $x+y=r^2$, this step confused me.

Comment: Sorry, I got a mistake in the last comment. It is not true that $x^2+y^2=r^2$ implies $x+y=r^2$. But $x+y=k$ with $k>r^2$ since $k$ is the ordinate of the red point. This suffice to say that $r^2<g(x_1,y_1)< g(x_2,y_2)=R^2$